# "Trying to access array offset on value of type int" - Laravel 8 Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to PHP and Laravel, I have written a Controller which call a RestAPI.
The API delivers following structure:

```
{
    "platform": "Unix",
    "hostname": "...",
    "guid": "...",
    "panel_version": "...",
    "panel_revision": "...",
    "panel_build_date": "...",
    "panel_update_version": "",
    "extension_version": "...",
    "extension_release": "..."
}
```

i will pass this data into blade template like this;

```
return view('data', ['result' => $data]);
```

in blade php i made following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>platform</td>
        <td>hostname</td>
        <td>panel-version</td>
        <td>build-date</td>

    </tr>
        @foreach ($result as $item)
            <td>{{$item['platform']}}</td>
        @endforeach
    <tr>

    </tr>
</table>
```

i dont know why, but i get an error "Trying to access array offset on value of type int" in the {{$item['id']}} row.

any suggestions to solve this problem?

I know there are some more questions about this, all ive tried did not helped me.

Thank you

best regards!
Lars :)

Comment: You are passing `result` from controller and trying to access as `$data` in blade foreach.

Comment: change to   @foreach ($result as $item)   check the manual https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views

Comment: this was my mistake at creating the post -ive corrected this

Comment: it's not a multidimensional array so remove the foreach completely. also i think you want $result['guid']. There is no id in your data. Or maybe do just $item in foreach

Comment: Please remove this post if my comment helped you solve your issue. this is not laravel related. It seams you don't understand array structure and should not even be a question

Comment: Assuming you do not have a proper debugging tools set up, you can use the [dd](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd) function provided by Laravel to inspect your values. This way you can get some sense of the data you are dealing with.

Comment: its not an array -> it sould be Json, thats why im so confused. The dd function works as ist shoud and list all the data

Answer (score 0):

-SOLVED-

```
json_decode($result, true)]
```

the "true" option must needed to be set